# Camel AdviceWith not mocking out Endpoint

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a complex Camel integration test which currently is working fine with 2 routes. All AdviceWiths work perfectly fine and successfully mock out the .to() endpoints. However, when adding a new AdviceWith in order to mock out a to() in a new route, the test opens a connection instead of redirecting the message to the mockEndpoint. The AdviceWith is as follows:

```
 AdviceWithRouteBuilder.adviceWith(camelContext, CREATE_PERSON_ROUTE_ID, route ->
        route.weaveById(CREATE_PERSON_ENDPOINT).replace().to(mockCreatePersonEndpointUri));
```

This same format is working fine for another route, such as:

```
 AdviceWithRouteBuilder.adviceWith(camelContext, QUARANTINE_RECORD_PERSON_ROUTE_ID, route ->
            route.weaveById(PERSON_QUARANTINE_RECORD_ENDPOINT).replace().to(mockPersonQuarantineRecordEndpointUri));
```

The camel line where this issue occurs:

```
.to(housingEndpoint).id(CREATE_PERSON_ENDPOINT)
```

The endpoint in question:

```
        Endpoint housingEndpoint = HousingRestAPIEndpoint.getHousingRestAPIEndpoint(getContext());
```

Please see setup for the test:

```
        mockCreatePersonEndpoint = camelContext.getEndpoint(mockCreatePersonEndpointUri, MockEndpoint.class);
```

I am wondering if this is a bug because as stated, the exact same config works fine for other routes with endpoints that are mocked out. Also, if I extract the test code into its own class, the AdviceWith behaves as expected. Any ideas welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed, issue was that I was initializing a new CamelContext both in the test class and in the code being tested, resulting the AdviceWith essentially mocking out a route that was not being used.